# draw.io click to expand button

Tags: confluence, draw.io

I've created a draw.io diagram in confluence. I'm looking to create a "button" of sorts that when clicked opens sub items (example: dog is the main "button", when clicked, it opens 4 sub shapes that say "puppy", "adult" "senior" below that shape).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this you can show us?

Answer (score 2):

Use the OrgChart shape in the advanced section like [this](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=test#R5VdNc5swEP013AEltq%2BO47SXTjJxOz3LaANKhcQIYUx%2BfQUsX5adIdM2k2l8MXpaaVfvrR62Rzbp8YumWfJNMRBe6LOjR269MAzIitivGqlaZBEsWiDWnGHQAOz4CyDoI1pwBvkk0CglDM%2BmYKSkhMhMMKq1KqdhT0pMs2Y0BgfYRVS46E%2FOTNKiq2t%2FwL8Cj5Muc%2BDjzJ5Gv2KtCon5vJA8NZ92OqXdXhifJ5SpcgSRrUc2WinTPqXHDYia2462dt3dhdm%2Bbg3SzFmAOh2oKPDo9zqOEqoN1meqjpO85Kmg0o5uEpMKCwb2MTc2FgW0ueyc0vxFSUO7iKgecAn6e5XVUUYDNLAQNMv5vtm%2FXomlgDZwvHicoCfJNh%2BoFIyubAguCAnyWnWdiONyUJEsEEtGCvaCUOycuN97YM8%2BIIHnybxyyHRIBGb7DIcg9qrcDsBNA9iJmgIe1QS29K7rjra4VA37INkJ0jQcsAmPdaYJiwfekT2035hZbIVcFTrCKLy0toYYMGp5nn8Nghp%2BmGb8Ey6vPwGXq3%2FD5Y8c9P3%2BufbF0Bd0D6JdeqtirMHewMfGYkYJOuIXo6JQkxHnZcIN7DLanKq05j91Ayp4LO1zZJkAbYE61Z11Xy7jUzvAsYao0Lk97iPkrY286gVoG3DZ8MirDhGEU4e4cg2iDxkbxOLt%2FmCHIynOt%2FnSafOHIssqp9ffynvX9mucSDljAmbT78p2UZBZV%2BGyYZ%2F49Tk5%2FL8jh8P9yuF%2BzQrhvvj%2BV%2B6D05fle5IfBA77H93gx9YddNW6Dj9DgNkOj0sfFJdmEI4sp8L1v3q6LdqqcNWJJn0Z82QKHZl2ILnSn%2BaW9G%2BId7gldjj89G%2FVGv5fke1v).